# Returning a df as NoneType after function is ran under except statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, error-handling, custom-error-handling

I am having trouble with returning a DataFrame after some exception handling. What I'm doing is checking for a FileNotFoundError when reading in an excel file, if found then I am printing an error message and then re-running the function and trying to return the df then. However, on the second run, even if the file is found, it returns the df as a NoneType instead data from the excel file and raises an AttributeError when other functions try and use the df as a parameter.

Here's the code for the first function:

```
def read_wb():
    try:
        wb_name = input("What is the name of your workbook (add .xlsx): ")
        df = pd.read_excel(wb_name)
        return df
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Ooops... It looks like this file is spelled wrong or it's not in the same folder of the script. Try again.")
        read_wb()
```

Here is the error that I am getting if an error was caught and read_wb() is ran under the except statement:

```
def main():
    141     df = read_wb()
--> 142     df = modify_df(df)
    143     df = return_ws(df)
    144     repeat = input("Do want to run another file ('y' or 'n'): ").lower()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loc'
```

I've tried moving the "return df" to the end of the except statement and even placing it on the same indent level as try and except, it still returns a NoneType. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Here is the full error message:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\vn54jdq\Downloads\WFS Review Folders\Hams Filter Project.ipynb Cell 20 in <cell line: 146>()
    145         main()
    146 if __name__ == "__main__":
--> 147     main()

c:\Users\vn54jdq\Downloads\WFS Review Folders\Hams Filter Project.ipynb Cell 20 in main()
    139 def main():
    140     df = read_wb()
--> 141     df = modify_df(df)
    142     df = return_ws(df)
    143     repeat = input("Do want to run another file ('y' or 'n'): ").lower()

c:\Users\vn54jdq\Downloads\WFS Review Folders\Hams Filter Project.ipynb Cell 20 in modify_df(df)
     18 tic = time.perf_counter()
     19 ## This first part of the script goes through the list product_cat and product_cat_type. 
     20 ## If found, then it will mark a 'n' in the Chemical (Y/N) columns so it can be counted as an exclusion.
     21 ## Then it searches for product types that are in the key flags that we are searching for like chemical...etc
---> 23 df.loc[df[df['Product Category'].str.contains(r'(?:\b(?=\w)|(?!\w))(?:{})(?:\b(?<=\w)|(?<!\w))'.format('|'.join(sorted(map(re.escape, product_cat), key=len, reverse=True))), case=False, regex=True).fillna(False)].index, "Chemical (Y/N)"] = 'n' 
     24 df.loc[df[df['Product Type'].str.contains(r'(?:\b(?=\w)|(?!\w))(?:{})(?:\b(?<=\w)|(?<!\w))'.format('|'.join(sorted(map(re.escape, values_flattened), key=len, reverse=True))), case=False, regex=True).fillna(False)].index, "Chemical (Y/N)"] = 'n'
     25 df.loc[df[df['Product Type'].str.contains(r'(?:\b(?=\w)|(?!\w))(?:{})(?:\b(?<=\w)|(?<!\w))'.format('|'.join(sorted(map(re.escape, chem_values_flattened), key=len, reverse=True))), case=False, regex=True).fillna(False)].index, "Chemical (Y/N)"] = 'y'

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loc'
```

Comment: Don't use recursion to implement an indefinite loop. Just use a `while` statement and let the `return` statement terminate it.

Comment: But you aren't *returning* the return value of the recursive call. You make the call, ignore what it returns, and let the function implicitly return `None` by reaching the end of the statements to execute.

Comment: Got it working, I just added a ```While``` statement and let the return close it like @chepner recommended.

Answer (score 2):

Move `return df` to the end of the function (or move it to `else` block), and make `read_wb()` call return value:

```
def read_wb():
    try:
        wb_name = input("What is the name of your workbook (add .xlsx): ")
        df = pd.read_excel(wb_name)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Ooops... It looks like this file is spelled wrong or it's not in the same folder of the script. Try again.")
        return read_wb()
    return df
```